# Let H be the set of vectors of the form (s , 2+s), where (s) is a real number, is H a subspace of R2

Tags: linear-algebra

Let H be the set of vectors of the form (s, 2+s), where s is a real number, is H a subspace of R2

Is this essentially asking for me to check the 3 conditions for a subspace? such as if the Zero vector is in the vector space, If its closed under addition, and closed under multiplication?

Comment: yes it is asking that only and more over this is not a subspace as this is not containing the identity element the (0,0)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does not contain the origin so it's clearly not a vector space.